# Let A and B be $n \times n$ real matrices with same minimal polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ real matrices with same minimal polynomial. Then

(i) $A$ is similar to $B$.

(ii) $A-B$ is singular.

(iii) $A$ is diagonalizable if $B$ is so.

(iv) $A$ and $B$ commute.

I think only (iii) is the correct option, similar matrcies have same characteristics polynomial but the converse may not be true, $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\ne \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ though they have same minpoly $x(x-1)$ the same two matrices works as a counter example for (ii), am I right ?

Comment: Why downvote? The Question shows some work, and is otherwise perfectly fine.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I see one serious problem with this question: there is no question.

Comment: I think you're right: a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial splits a product of *different* linear factors...

Comment: @GitGud I am just a Taxi driver, please consider my mistake :(

Comment: @TaxiDriver I wasn't the downvoter. I'm guessing you're told only one of the options is correct and that you should pick the correct one. If this is so, then you should put it in the question.

Comment: actually the question paper from which I am solving these problems for my exam preparation has multiple correct options in some question and single correct option in some question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, and here are the two missing counterexamples:

(i) $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\&1\\&&1\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\&1\\&&1&1\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}$ both have minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$, but are not similar. (For example, similar matrices have the same dimension of the corresponding eigenspaces.)
(ii) Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}2\\&1\end{pmatrix}$, then $A-B=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\&1\end{pmatrix}$ is non-singular.
(iii) DonAntonio provided an excellent explanation why this is true in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411450/let-a-and-b-be-n-times-n-real-matrices-with-same-minimal-polynomial#comment880520_411450).
(iv) Your counterexample, that this is not true, is correct.